# zypper equivalent to yum groupupdate?

Tags: opensuse, zypper

Is there an equivalent command?

Tried the obvious:

```
$ zypper update -t pattern <pattern name>
Warning: The /etc/products.d/baseproduct symlink is dangling or missing!
The link must point to your core products .prod file in /etc/products.d.

Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Package '<pattern name>' is not installed.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
```

I see in the documentation that removal by pattern is not implemented -- is it the same story for update?

Answer (score 0):

afaik, `zypper update` does the same ase `yum update; that is:

- `zypper update` will try to update all installed packages
- `zypper update package-name` will try to update the package with name "package-name".

Comment: But no groupupdate - correct?

Comment: no; you can update a "group"; which is called a "pattern" in zypper; using: `zypper update -t pattern <pattern name>`. Note that you have to replace `<pattern name>` by the name of the installed pattern (group) you want to update.